# Angular custom reuse strategy reload that component

Tags: angular, components, reusability

There's a problem with Custom Reuse Strategy I've been working all around and I can't see any solution. Maybe one of yours is able to help me.

So. I implemeted to my application Custom Reuse Strategy. It works just fine, additionally I added a list of adressess that I don't want to be stored. Here's the code :

```
import {RouteReuseStrategy, DetachedRouteHandle, ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from "@angular/router";

export class CustomRoutingReuse implements RouteReuseStrategy{
handlers: {[key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle} = {};
private ignoredRoutes : String[] = [
    'module_one/:id',
    'module_one/:id/mod',
    'module_one/:id/something_else',
];

shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    //console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldDetach', route);
    if(this.ignoredRoutes.indexOf(route.routeConfig.path) > -1){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}

store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:store', route, handle);
    this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path] = handle;
}

shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldAttach', route);
    return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
}

retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:retrieve', route);
    if (!route.routeConfig) return null;
    return this.handlers[route.routeConfig.path];
}

shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    console.debug('CustomReuseStrategy:shouldReuseRoute', future, curr);
    return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
}
```

}

And now just imagine. First route on the list :

```
module_one/:id
```

Shows me details of something. And the second one :

```
module_one/:id/mod
```

allows me to change some values of the details from first route, then send them to backend and do some insert to DB.

And now... I don't want first route in there. It's a component that handles inside 5 more. And when it's remembered, after changing value and coming back to it, the value still remains, because the whole component was remembered.

It's a little bit messy, I know. Here is what I'm looking for :

- I want to make a list in customReuseStrategy like :

  ```
  private ignoredComponents : String[] = [
  'myModuleOneComponent'];
  ```

  And detach component by it's name.
- or I need a way to tell component to reload itself or just do my instructions after coming back to it, when it's stored.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this problem, you can find the component name inside `route.component.name`

```
shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
  return this.ignoredComponents.indexOf(route.component.name) === -1;
}
```